# How to retrieve value form url in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using url given below

```
http://192.168.1.51/aristov1/sushiladmin/?#/app/form/update_visa/197
```

how can i get the value of 197. while i am using

```
console.log($stateParams.vid);
```

it shows undefined.

Comment: It would help to post your states definition.

Answer (score 0):

In app.js where you define the urls, you will need to append id there.

```
.state('Visa', {
                   url                 : '/form/update_visa/:id',
                   controller          : 'VisaCtrl',
                   templateUrl         : 'visa/form.html',
               });
```

and now in the controller you can get that value with `$stateParams.id`